# How to get vehicle's spare parts in minimum cost?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a data file have shop id, cost, items, what algorithm should I use to get all asked spare parts from a *single* shop in minimum prize. If no single shop can be found, 'None' should be printed. Also, there's no harm in purchasing *extra* spare parts within minimum prize.

```
Shop ID,    Cost($),    Items List
1,          4.00,       E
1,          8.00,       F
2,          5.00,       E
2,          6.50,       F
5,          4.00,       A
5,          8.00,       D
6,          5.00,       D
6,          6.00,       A, B, C  ; Here in 6$ three items can be obtained
7,          2.20,       B
7,          3.00,       B,C
7,          2.00,       B
7,          2.50,       C

a) Spare Parts : A,D

Output:
Shop ID-6 
Cost - 11.0$

b) Spare Parts : E,F

Output:
Shop ID-2 
Cost - 11.5$
```

---

My approach (which doesn't work):

a) Get common Shops Ids first for given input

```
shop_id_list=[]
for items in input_list:
    shop_id_list = getCommonShopIds(items.strip(), shop_id_list )
    all_items.append( items )
```

b) For each `all_items` get minimum cost of that item in all `shop_id_list`, ( 0 if items already included in last iteration)

```
res = [0 for x in range(len(shop_id_list)) ]
for items in all_items:
    all_cost = getMinShopCost( shop_id_list, items )
    res= map(operator.add, all_cost, res ) # Add those list
```

c) Find minimum element index in res (say `i`) and print the corresponding `shop_id_list[i]` and  `res[i]`

My logic doesn't work for cases like:

Input : B C

It prints 7 4.5$

Expected should be 7 3.00$

Is this is any standard problem, or variation of any graph theory problem, etc ?

I am not able to figure out any optimized approach, any help will be appreciated.

<sup>*PS: Python is only tagged since the question has python code snippet, I'm just interested in approach. Also, this is not any problem from online going contest, not that I'm aware of.*</sup>

Comment: There's 2 steps here. You first need to find which places can satisfy the constraint. Call this set S. If S is empty then you return none. If S is not empty then you calculate the cost of getting it from each of the places in S. You return the place that has the lowest cost of the places in S. The problem is a lot more difficult if you can get parts from more than one place.

Comment: How many different parts are there, roughly?

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's not specified/unknown, data is supposed to be inputted from a csv file

Comment: I ask because there's a simple DP algorithm that is exponential in the number of different products, so it will be ideal if that is less than around ~20, but totally useless if it's > 30.

Comment: Also: How can it be that you don't know even roughly how many different parts there could be?  Isn't there someone you can ask about this?  Otherwise it sounds like it *is* an online contest problem...

Comment: @j_random_hacker Whatever it may sounds like, but it was a _randomly cooked_ problem at a job interview of one of my senior friend, I don't deny that it couldn't be from online contest problem. But yes one thing I can assure you is that I didn't copied/tweaked and pasted it from internet. Please do post the approach if you have one in mind, it will be appreciated.

Comment: Well I don't have time to give a full solution, but the gist is: Treat each shop separately, and assume some order on the parts (e.g. alphabetic).  Build up a complete list of the optimal prices for getting *any* subset of the items available at the current shop using DP with the following recurrence: for any set of parts X, let m be the highest part in X according to the (e.g. alphabetic) ordering, and let optPrice(X) = min{optPrice(X\Y)+price(Y)}, where the minimum is taken over all offered part-sets (i.e. rows in your table) Y that contain m.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 steps here.

First step: You first need to find which places can satisfy the constraint of having all of the required parts in stock. Call the set of places that meets this constraint set S. If S is empty then you return none. If S is not empty and there's more than one location then you go to the second step.

Second step: Y have to calculate the cost of getting the parts from each of the places in S. To calculate the cost for an individual place is a constraint satisfaction problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem. There are a few ways in which you might go about solving this. One way is to use a mixed integer [LP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) based approach with the following formulation:

```
Let X be the item groups bought
let y_1, .. y_n be the items you require

min F(X) = \sum cost(X)
subject to:
y_i \in X, for i \in {1,..,n}
```

Essentially you have some binary constraints. There's most likely better ways of formulating this, but this hopefully gives you the general idea.
You could possibly solve this with some LP solver like the simplex method.

If you are using Python have a look at these solver libraries:
http://www.scipy.org/
https://software.sandia.gov//trac/coopr
https://code.google.com/p/pulp-or/

After the costs are calculated you return the place that has the lowest cost of the places in S

Comment: +1 Thanks for the approach, I'm trying to understand, it might take some time for me

Comment: @P0W, glad this helps. I did stuff like this for quite a few years. I think an attempt at solving this question would make for a fantastic blog post, so I'll do that if I can get the time.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is small then simple backtracking would do :-

> 1. Do for each shop
> 2. select a offer yet unselected and containing atleast a subset of unpurchased items.
> 3. make the offer as selected and mark all items covered by it as selected.
> 4. recursively select until all items exhausted or no viable offer exists.
> 5. record the min cost of all possible purchases.

Further you can also prevent recursion if the cost already exceeds the current min cost.

If the number of offer is small then use also do brute force :-

> 1. select a subset of offers and marks all items it covers.
> 2. generate a n bit number from it.
> 3. Put in a hashmap n => min cost.

This is very effective if you have multiple orders as then you just have to lookup in the hashmap by making a n bit number of the order.

You can also try **branch and bound** technique with estimate like **sum of items taken individually**